# What to do to improve this jumping code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this iOS game where the frog jumps from lily pad to lily pad. The game is in the vertical orientation, and the perspective I'm trying to achieve is an aerial view, where the user looks at the frog and scenery from the top. The frog jumps from lily pad to lily pad and the code is the following:

Bounce Method:

```
-(void)bounce {
        [self jumpSound];

        if (frog.center.y > 450) {
            upMovement = 2;
        }
        else if (frog.center.y > 350) {
            upMovement = 1.5;
        }
        else if (frog.center.y > 250) {
            upMovement = 0.5;
        }
}
```

and the lilypad movement:

```
-(void)lilyPadMovement {

   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(frog.frame, lily.frame) && (upMovement <=-1)){
        [self bounce];
        [self lilyPadFall];
        if (lilyPadUsed == NO) {
            addedScore = 1;
            lilyPadUsed = YES;
        }
    }

}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to fix is the frogs bouncing movement. When the frog lands in the middle of a lily pad and bounces it doesn't look bad, but at times the frog will simply touch the sides of the lil pad and the bounce method will be called because the rectangles intersected. I tried `CGRectContainsRect` but it made the game to hard, because it delayed the speed of the game. So I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to know if there's a sufficient overlap to enable the frog to push off, rather than fall in the water. So maybe the distance between the centers has to be less than X, where you tune X based on what looks good.

For example ( using the Pythagorean formula) :

```
 //having defined this function: 
inline float square (float a) { return a*a; }
 //change intersect test to:
 if (((square(frog.center.x-lily.center.x) + square(frog.center.y-lily.center.y)) < 10000) && 
     (upMovement <= -1)) { ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Set something up like cgrectintersectsrect && (frog.center.x < lily.center.x)

Comment: Actually, I mean compute the distance between the centers using the Pythagorean formula. See above edit.

Comment: Note that I'm comparing to the square of 100, rather than computing the "real" distance using the square root, as it's faster. 100 is what needs to be tuned to whatever distance is appropriate for your particular graphics.

Comment: @mackworth, are you aware that `^` is C's XOR operator?

Comment: I am, but every time I come back to c I forget it!  fixed above... thx